# Filtering GeoJSON data to include in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, json

I am trying to filter through my geojson polygons and get all data entries with a specific attribute.

I have a layer of polygons describing parks around the city `parks.json`. I want the user to click on a button and see parks that have picnic areas. I have GeoJson data in the following format:

`{"type":"Feature",
"geometry":{
    "type":"Polygon",
    "coordinates":[[[long1, lat1],[long2, lat2],[long3, lat3]]]},
    "properties":
{
    "Playground": Yes,
    "Picnic":Yes,
    "ParkName":"Barr Lake",
    "ParkStatus":"Open"}`

How do I retrieve all of the polygons where "Picnic" = "Yes" and map them?

I tried this with no luck:

`var picnic_parks = $("parks.json").filter(' "picnic":"Yes" ').addTo(map);`

Comment: How could I add this filter in this script: var featureLayer = L.geoJson(null, { filter: function(feature, layer) { return feature.geometry.coordinates[0] !== 0 && feature.geometry.coordinates[1] !== 0; }, pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) { return L.marker(latlng, { title: feature.properties["status_title_github"], riseOnHover: true, icon: L.icon({ iconUrl: "assets/pictures/markers/cb0d0c.png", iconSize: [30, 40], iconAnchor: [15, 32] }) }); }, onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { if (feature.properties) { layer.on({ click: function (e) { identifyFeature(L.stamp(layer)); highligh

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135598)

Answer (score 23):

The `L.GeoJson` class has a built in [filter option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson-filter) that you can use to filter your data. Just pass it a function that will return `true` for the features you want to show:

```
var picnic_parks = L.geoJson(myJson, {filter: picnicFilter}).addTo(map);

function picnicFilter(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.Picnic === "Yes") return true
}
```

Here is a fiddle with a working example of this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/nathansnider/9mgnd389/

Comment: Great, this worked! However, I'm observing that I can't have two of these layers displaying at once--both `picnic_parks` and the complete data `L.geoJson(myJson)` won't be added to the map together. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Hmm, you should have no problem adding layers with different (or no) filtering options from the same GeoJSON. In the jsfiddle, for example, if you add a second layer with `var polyLayer2 = L.geoJson(myJson).addTo(map);`, it will display both the filtered data and the original unfiltered data. How are you trying to show the complete data?

Comment: I'm drawing the full data with `L.geoJson(data,{style:myStyle}).addTo(map); }); `. I can draw the layers separately but not together. Everything is similar to your example except I'm bringing in my .json with `$.getJSON(parks.json)` (it's a big file, too much to have in the code). I might have made an error there; might ask another question / play around some more. Thanks again, this was a big step forward for me.